# Magento 2 html data-bind call function

Tags: magento2.3

In file html i write

```
 <div data-bind=" $parent.checkPaymentPage() ">...</div>
```

In file js i have

```
checkPaymentPage: function(){
    console.log(1);
}
```

But when i call and reload it not console.log(1). How can i call it? Please help me!

Comment: Any console error ?

Comment: Did you run the static content command after adding/updating the JS/HTML code? Also please clear your browser cache to review the changes.

Comment: yes any console.as long as I call the checkPaymentPage function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the knockout HTML you can use the data-bind with the various [binding map](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ui_comp_guide/concepts/magento-bindings.html#binding-map)

in order to just call the component file function, you can use data-bind with `afterRender` so whenever you div was loaded this function call.

```html
<div data-bind="afterRender: checkPaymentPage">...</div>
```

in the js file you can write the function.

```js
checkPaymentPage: function(){ console.log(1); },
```

Ex. if you are using an observable variable

```js
isVisible: ko.observable(false),
isLoading: ko.observable(false),
```

You can use the below code

```html
<div data-bind="fadeVisible: isVisible() , blockLoader: isLoading()" id="component-container">.....</div>
```